# FCKEditor toolbar configuration not work

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I am trying to change the file fckconfig.js in order to change the toolbar:

this is the configuration in fckconfig.js:

`FCKConfig.ToolbarSets["Basic"] = [
    ['Bold','Italic','-','OrderedList','UnorderedList','-','Link','Unlink','-','About'],
        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyFull']
] ;`

I removed/add some buttons:

`FCKConfig.ToolbarSets["Basic"] = [
    ['Bold','Italic','-','FontSize','-','Link','Unlink','-','About'],
        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyFull']
] ;`

but it didnot work??

Comment: It looks the same.  If possible, you should also consider upgrading to ckeditor. fckeditor is quite old now.

Comment: you are right, I changed it. what new in ckeditor?

Comment: Quite a few things http://ckeditor.com/whatsnew

Comment: I didnot got the answer, it still not working

Comment: please, anyone know whats wrong??

Comment: It could be because you attempted to override a default toolbar set. Try making a custom named set instead per http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar